# MOXy marshalling wrong object

Tags: jaxb, moxy, docx4j, wordprocessingml

I'm trying to have docx4j support MOXy as its JAXB implementation.

We're pretty much there; see [docx4j and MOXy](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/moxy-t1242.html)

The problem I'm having is that I have a [class](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/wml/Text.java):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", name = "CT_Text", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "t")
public class Text
```

MOXy is marshalling this to w:delInstrText, instead of w:t, which is what I'd expect/hope, and what the Java 6 / reference implementations do.

From the [schema](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/xsd/wml/wml.xsd):

```
        <xsd:element name="t" type="CT_Text">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Text</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:element name="delInstrText" type="CT_Text">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Deleted Field Code</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
```

FWIW, ObjectFactory contains:

```
public Text createText() {
    return new Text();
}

@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main", name = "delInstrText", scope = R.class)
public JAXBElement<Text> createRDelInstrText(Text value) {
    return new JAXBElement<Text>(_RDelInstrText_QNAME, Text.class, R.class, value);
}
```

This is with MOXy jars:

```
        +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:jar:2.4.1
        |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.4.1
        |  |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:3.3.1.v201206041142
        |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:jar:3.2.0.v201206041011
```

**Update:**

Here is a test case:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import org.docx4j.wml.R;
import org.docx4j.wml.Text;


public class MOXyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.docx4j.wml");
//        System.out.println(Version.getVersion());
//        System.out.println(jc.getClass());

        R run = new R();
        Text text = new Text();
        run.getContent().add(text);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(run, System.out);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

---

**UPDATE**

We have been able to reproduce the error you are seeing in EclipseLink 2.4.1.  We have not been able to reproduce the issue in the EclipseLink 2.4.2 or 2.5.0 streams.  I would recommend downloading the latest 2.4.2 nightly build and trying it out:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

We are still investigating this issue to ensure that it is truly fixed.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

So far I have been unable to reproduce the results from your question when MOXy is used as the JAXB provider.  Could you provide some additional information to help me reproduce your use case.  Below is what I have tried so far:

**Java Model**

I took the Java model from the following location on GitHub:

- https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/main/java

**jaxb.properties**

I added a file called `jaxb.properties` in the `org.docx4j.wml` package to enable MOXy as the JAXB provider.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Demo**

Below is the demo code I used to try and reproduce the issue:

```java
package org.docx4j.wml;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.Version;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.docx4j.wml");
        System.out.println(Version.getVersion());
        System.out.println(jc.getClass());

        Text text = new Text();

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(text, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.  I'm seeing the proper root element `t` marshalled out instead of `delInstrText` as described in the question.

```
2.4.1
class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:t xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"/>
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a variation on your demo code which reproduces the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @JasonPlutext - Thanks for updating your question.  I have updated my answer with our findings.

Comment: Verified that with eclipselink-2.4.2.v20121107 the issue seems to have gone away.  Thanks for looking into this.